# how can i use weka to terminology extraction?

Tags: text, terminology, weka, categorization

i need to extract domain-specific terms from a big training corpus, such as political terms or etc .how can i use Weka and it's filters to aim this object?
can i use feature vector produced by `StringToVector()` filter in Weka to do this or not?

Answer (score 1):

You can at least partly, as far as you have an appropriate dataset. For instance, let us assume you have a dataset like this one:

```
@relation test

@attribute text String
@attribute politics {yes,no}
@attribute religion {yes,no}

@data
"this is a text about politics",yes,no
"this text is about religion",no,yes
"this text mixes everything",yes,yes
```

For instance, for getting terms about *politics*, you can:

1. Remove the *religion* attribute.
2. Apply the `StringToWordVector` filter to the text attribute to get terms.
3. Apply the `AttributeSelection` filter with `Ranker` and `InfoGainAttributeEval` to get the top ranked terms.

This latter step will give you a list of terms that are most predictive for the *politics* category. Most of them will be terms in the *politics* domain (although it is possible that some terms are predictive but just because they are not in the politics domain - that is, they provide negative evidence).

The quality of the terms you get depens on the dataset. The more topics it deals with, the better for your results; so instead of having two classes (*politics*, *religion*, like in my dataset), it is much better to have plenty of them and many examples for each category.

Comment: thank you.but i can not understand step 1.because my arff file is in this fomat(using TextDirectoryLoader):
`   @relation 'TestCats'
    @attribute @@class@@ {mis,pol}
    
    @data
    'this is politic text ...',pol
    'this text is not politic ....',mis
'
how can i remove mis attribiut?

Comment: In your case, classes are overlapping and you cannot make use of the step 3 because it will give you the list of words that best predict all classes at once. So you have to get the same format as I have proposed. For this, you can make us of the filter `MakeIndicator` to transform the nominal class into several attributes, one per value.